# Backdate of video feed on page when using graph api facebook on C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I search on graph api that when post video have backdated_post parameter.
But I dont know how to declare it.

On https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video, that backdated_post is json array have 3 paramter inside : backdated_time, backdated_time_granularity, hide_from_newsfeed.

And I declare [{"backdated_time": "2/12/2016"}], graph api show me error : "backdated_time not declare" or something simaliar.

Graph api I'm using that ver 2.10.

This is my code

```
var url = $"https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.10/{idOrUserNameOfPage}/videos?access_token={accessTokenPage}";

  using (var content =
              new MultipartFormDataContent(AnotherUtils.GenerationBoundary()))
    {
         var streamContent = new StreamContent(streamVideo);
    var videoContent = new ByteArrayContent(await streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
    streamContent.Dispose();

   videoContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");        
                    StringContent messageContent = new StringContent(message, Encoding.UTF8);
    List<dynamic> listDynamic = new List<dynamic>();
                      listDynamic.Add(new
                               {
                                    backdated_time = datePost,
                                    backdated_time_granularity = "none",
                                    hide_from_newsfeed = false
                                });
                                var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listDynamic);
    StringContent postDatePageContent = new StringContent(jsonString,Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
     content.Add(postDatePageContent, "backdated_post");
     content.Add(messageContent, "description");
                    content.Add(videoContent, "file", "file.mp4");
                    var response = await _customHttpClient.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

And facebook show error : (#100) Invalid format for BackdatedPost, backdated_time must be defined.

Anyone help me ?? pls

Comment: First of all you need to specify `backdated_post`, and that needs to be an array.

Comment: also, please include the relevant code in your question, and the exact api call.

Comment: I also include code @luschn

Comment: @CBroe I know, and I specify backdate_post that json-Array which facebook tell me.